# How to fix Ldap error after Java 17 upgrade

Tags: java, spring, ldap, jndi

I am getting the following error in catalina.out after Java 17 upgrade. I updated the dependency to following as other post suggested but still getting the error. I am running Java-17-openjdk-17.0.9.0.9-2.el9.x86_64 and tomcat-9.0.82.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in unnamed module @0x7e9e53cb) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module @0x7e9e53cb
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.<clinit>(AbstractContextSource.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295)
    ... 105 more
```

Comment: If you use Java 17 you need to use Spring 6 / SpringBoot classes.   And Tomcat 10.1 or later.

Comment: *" I updated the dependency to following as other post suggested but still getting the error. "* - For future reference ... saying that is not helpful.  You didn't say what posts you are talking about, what dependencies you update, what you updated them too.  And we don't know for sure what you DIDN'T update.  Since the problem is (most likely) in the dependencies that you haven't told us about ....